# Facebook's share dialog apperaring cut with Portuguese label on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm here again to once more ask about Facebook SDK for Android.
In my application, the user can login and share some content on his account.
Ok until here, now the problem is the share dialog.

After login, this dialog is opened, but how my application is in Portuguese the button Share appears 'Compartilhar' and because of that, this word is bigger, the button is cutted by the dialog, thing that doesn't happen with the english label Share.
Also I realize that the labels of dialogs changing according device's language (reason why I discovered that english label Share appears normally), is there a way for define a default language for that? My application language for default is already Portuguese.

Also, I'd like to know if there's a way to change the label of that button, or something else because I already tried to increase the widht of the dialog and didn't work. I'm using Facebook SDK for Android v3.0

Thanks in advance.